# Deprecation of success Parameter in jQuery.ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Today I have heard that the success-Parameter in the jQuery.ajax function is deprecated. Have I understood that correctly? Or am i missunderstanding something?

For Example this would not work in the future:

```
 $.ajax({

            url: 'ax_comment.php',              
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'mode=view&note_id='+noteid+'&open='+open+'&hash='+hash,
            success: function(a) {
            ...

            }   

    });
```

And i have to use this?

```
$.ajax({

            url: 'ax_comment.php',

            type: 'POST',
            data: 'mode=view&note_id='+noteid+'&open='+open+'&hash='+hash,
            success: function(a) {
            ...

            }   

    }).done(function(a){.....};
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ (Scroll down to **Deprecation Notice**)

Comment: Yes.. you need to use `.done()` Jquery would still have that feature, till whenever they decide to pull the plug :)

Comment: The parameter is not being deprecated, the success method is. You can continue using `success: function` re-read it carefully.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

There is a difference between, the Ajax success **callback method**:

```
$.ajax({}).success(function(){...});
```

and the Ajax success **local callback event** (i.e., the Ajax parameter and property):

```
$.ajax({
    success: function(){...}
});
```

The **success callback method** (first example) is being deprecated. However, the **success local event** (second example) is not.

Local events are Ajax properties (i.e., parameters).  The jQuery docs further explain that the [local event](https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/) *is a callback that you can subscribe to within the Ajax request object*.

So in future, you may do either:

```
$.ajax({}).done(function(){...});
```

or

```
$.ajax({
    success: function(){...}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is deprecated in jQuery 1.8 onwards. You should use `.done()` and use `.fail()` to catch the errors.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'URL',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { // Your Data },
    datatype: 'json'
})
.done(function (data) { // AJAX Success })
.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { // AJAX Failure });
```