# codeigniter submit ajax alert success

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

i have this form that submits personal details

here is my view

```
<?php $attributes=a rray( 'autocomplete'=>"off", 'id' => 'theForm');?>
<?php echo form_open_multipart( 'employee/personaldetails', $attributes); ?>
<div class="row">
<div class="span3 offset1">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input onkeypress="return fnAllowAlpha(event);" maxlength="50" type="text" value="<?php echo $info['first_name']; ?>" name="first_name" disabled>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $info['employee_image']; ?>" name="employee_image" disabled>
</div>
<div class="span3">
    <label>Middle Name</label>
    <input onkeypress="return fnAllowAlpha(event);" maxlength="50" type="text" value="<?php echo $info['middle_name']; ?>" name="middle_name" disabled>
</div>
<div class="span3">
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input onkeypress="return fnAllowAlpha(event);" maxlength="50" type="text" value="<?php echo $info['last_name']; ?>" name="last_name" disabled>
</div>
<div class="span1">
    <div class="down1">
        <button type="submit" class="button-orange" id="btnSave" style="display:none;">Save</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

CONTROLLER

```
$this->load->model('mdl_employee','emp');
$id = $this->session->userdata('id');
$P1 = $this->input->post('first_name');
$P2 = $this->input->post('middle_name');
$P3 = $this->input->post('last_name');
$this->emp->update_myinfo($id, $P1, $P2, $P3);
```

model

```
public function update_myinfo($id, $P1, $P2, $P3){
  $employee_data = array(
           'first_name' => $P1,
           'middle_name' => $P2,
           'last_name' => $P3);
$this->db->where('employee_id', $id);
$this->db->update('employee', $employee_data);
}
```

i dont know how to use ajax.
i want to alert the ajax if success or not. after updating my database.. im just new programmer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try googling since its so common to submit forms using ajax.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/

[Submitting HTML form using Jquery AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323360/submitting-html-form-using-jquery-ajax)

I would suggest first try these links..and if u still get stuck then let us know, we would surely help you :)