# How to submit form data with Zurb Foundation

Tags: forms, zurb-foundation

I'm a beginner trying to set up my first form with Zurb Foundation, and I'm not able to find in the documentation the info on how to actually pass the data. It's just a basic contact form with name/email/message that I'd like sent to my email once people click the Submit button... and I don't know how to do that.

I apologize for the simple question, your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zurb foundation is front end frame work for website design and development , if you want to submit the form or do server communications, please read some basics,

HTML form and input : http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Submitting HTML form using Jquery AJAX :

[Submitting HTML form using Jquery AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323360/submitting-html-form-using-jquery-ajax)

AJAX - Send a Request To a Server : http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Answer (score 0):

The **HTML** part:

```
<form action="form_contact_process.php" method="POST" name="contact" id="contact">
<fieldset>
<legend>Contact form</legend>
    <div class="row collapse">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    </div>
    <div class="row collapse">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
    </div>
    <div class="row collapse">
        <label for="phone">Phone</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone">
    </div>
    <div class="row collapse">
        <label for="message">Message</label>
        <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="row collapse">
        <input class="button small large-12" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Then over at **form_contact_process.php**:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
...

echo $name;
```