# Why does my html output disappear?

Tags: javascript, html

The below code displays the "Test" only for the loading period of the page and then it disappears..please advise

```
<input style="margin-left:40px;" type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" onclick="myFunction()"></input>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
document.getElementById("div6").innerHTML="Test";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Once the form is submitted, the page is refreshed. Do you want to prevent the form submission? Or do you want the "Test" message to persist after submission?

Comment: I see no element with an ID of div6.

Comment: @showdev I want the test message to persist after submission

Comment: @j08691 it actually is:                                                                                       <input style="margin-left:40px;" type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" onclick="myFunction() return false"></input>
  </form>
  
  <div id="div6">
   
  </div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the form is submitted, the page is reloaded without the "Test" message.

Since you want the "Test" message to persist after form submission, I suggest some server-side code to display it conditionally (if the form has been submitted).

Using PHP, it would go something like this:

```
<?php

// determine if the form was submitted
$submitted=isset($_POST['submitted']) ? true : false;

?>

<form method="post" onsubmit="myFunction();" >
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submitted" />
</form>

<!-- echo message if form was submitted -->
<div id="div6"><?php echo $submitted ? "Test" : ""; ?></div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("div6").innerHTML="Test";
}
</script>
```

Alternatively, you could [submit the form using AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323360/submitting-html-form-using-jquery-ajax) so that the page does not reload.
But that's a different story.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
function myFunction(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("div6").innerHTML="Test";
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: just now I have tried it...now, not only after the page load but also from the beginning of the page load the "Test" not appears

Answer (score 0):

The form is submitting and the page is reloading. that is why your text is "disappearing". Since the button is a submit button, the form will submit whenever the function returns true (default). You can prevent this by returning false:

```
<input style="margin-left:40px;" type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" onclick="myFunction(); return false"/>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
    document.getElementById("div6").innerHTML="Test";
}
</script>
```

Comment: I have tried it but unfortunately I still face the same trouble