# Show loading image while its uploading?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image upload form, which auto uploads the image when user selects the file.

Upload form

```
<form id="imageupload" action="./uploadres.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input type="file" name="file" value="Ekle" accept="image/*" size="20">
</form>
```

Auto upload script when user selected file

```
$("input[name='file']").change(function() {

this.form.submit(); 

});
```

Show/hide loading image function:

```
$('#loadimg').show();
$('#contents').load(function(){
$('#loadimg').hide();
});
```

What I am trying to do is showing loading image while its uploading. What is the correct way to integrate the Show/hide loading image method into my form submit ?

Comment: Is the upload done with XHR or POST?

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing a full HTML post, then you only have one option:

Using the form's [`onsubmit` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onsubmit) to display the uploading symbol. This will be cleared when the new HTML is downloaded.

On the other hand, if you are using jQuery to submit the form, there are a several excellent ways to handle that.

I'd point you [to this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323360/submitting-html-form-using-jquery-ajax) for an overview.

Comment: File uploads are trickier than regular `POST`s. The discussion you linked is only about regular `POST`.

Comment: The discussion I linked to what about using an `ajax` post.

Comment: Yes, for a form that doesn't have file inputs. `$.ajax` doesn't support file inputs (because it can't, on older browsers).