# Bootstrap Validator Form message to load on the same page

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've been looking to solve this, but i can't find a way to do it. I already tried other methods i found in here, but none of them were working for me.

I'm building a website with Bootstrap and also using Bootstrap Validator to make a Contact Form. I can make it work perfect and also submit the contact, but the "thank you message" is redirected to another page. I want the "Thank you message" to load on the same page, and take the place of the form, since its a one scrolling page website.

Can anyone help me please? This is the code i have so far:
Ps.: All my CSS file are the original from bootstrap, nothing has been changed.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- form: -->
            <section>
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <div class="page-header">
                        <h2>Formulário de contato.</h2>
                    </div>

                    <form id="defaultForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="contact-2.php">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Nome completo</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" placeholder="Nome" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" placeholder="Sobrenome" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Assunto</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-5">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" placeholder="WebSite" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">E-mail</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-5">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="email@contato.com" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Telefone</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-5">
                                <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="tel" placeholder="48 0000 0000" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Mensagem</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-5">
                                <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="10" placeholder="Escreva aqui sua mensagem."></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-lg-3 control-label" id="captchaOperation"></label>
                            <div class="col-lg-2">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="captcha" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-lg-9 col-lg-offset-3">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="signup" value="Sign up">Enviar</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="resetBtn">Limpar</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </section>
            <!-- :form -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

PHP Contact

```
<?php

// getting 
$firstname     = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname     = $_POST['lastname'];
$email    = trim($_POST['email']);
$emailtosend = 'myemail@hotmail.com'; //E-mail to receive message
$tel           = $_POST['tel'];
$subject          = $_POST['subject'];
$message          = $_POST['message'];


/* Message to show on email. */
$mensagemHTML = '<P>Contact form sent by the website.</P>
<p><b>First Name:</b> '.$firstname.'
<p><b>Last Name:</b> '.$lastname.'
<p><b>E-Mail:</b> '.$email.'

<p><b>Telephone:</b> '.$tel.'
<p><b>Subject:</b> '.$subject.'
<p><b>Message:</b> '.$message.'</p>
<hr>';


// 
// 
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.1\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$headers .= "From: $email\r\n"; // remetente
$headers .= "Return-Path: $emailtosend \r\n"; // return-path
$envio = mail($email, $subject, $mensagemHTML, $headers); 

 if($envio)
//echo "<script>location.href='sucesso.html'</script>"; // Página que será redirecionada

?>
```

If there is anyone here able to help me with it, that would be great!

Comment: You do need AJAX because your PHP code is in a separate page and you want to display the _thank you message_ on the same page. I recommend you start reading on AJAX and read more posts and tutorials like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323360/submitting-html-form-using-jquery-ajax) and [this.](http://hayageek.com/jquery-ajax-form-submit/)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the code below. You need AJAX. Place this in your html page.
The whole project of that code can be found at [this link](https://github.com/ekonstantinidis/ProjectEnquiry) (just in case you want to see other files too).

```
    $(function() {
      $("#myform button").click(function() {

        // Get form values
        var name = $("input#name").val();
        var email = $("input#email").val();
        var comments = $("textarea#comments").val();

        // Validate and prepare values for php
        var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&comments=' + comments;

        // Post data to the php file
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST", 
          url: "bin/process-form.php",
          async:false, // Wait for the result
          data: dataString,
          success: function(data) {
              if (data=="Email Sent Successfully!"){
                $('#myform').html("<div id='message'></div>");
                $('#message').html("<h2>Enquiry Form Submitted!</h2>")
                    .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>")
                    .hide()
                    .fadeIn(1500, function() {
                      $('#message').append("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span>");
                    });
            } else {
                    $("#myform-errors").show();
                    $('#myform-errors').html(data);
                }
          }
        });
        return false;

  });
```

Comment: I tried to use this, but the only thing i'm getting is to clean the form after i click on the submit button and the page goes back to the top. But i have no message and no e-mail receiving in my account. I double checked it looking at the scripts you gave in the link. Any idea?

Comment: Did you edit the code I suggested? You have to add your fields so that it passes all the values to the php file.

Comment: Yes, i made those changes. This is the pastbin of my HTML, just the part you said to put: http://pastebin.com/n2iMBNa5 - I also made a little change on the form top remove the action (there is an example in the pastbin file as well). The contact-2.php i didn't changed.