# dajaxice: something went wrong

Tags: django, dajaxice, dajax

I have a `ul` list and a button:

```
<form>{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="list-arrows col-md-1 text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm move-left">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

This triggers my ajax request:

```
function publListChanged()
{
    var publs = $('.list-right ul li.active');
    Dajaxice.awv_public.reload_stats(Dajax.process, {'publs': '10'})
}


$(function () {

    [...]
    $('.list-arrows button').click(function () {
        var $button = $(this), actives = '';
        if ($button.hasClass('move-left')) {
            publListChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Currently, for debugging, my method does nothing:

```
@dajaxice_register
def reload_stats(request, publs):
    dajax = Dajax()
    return dajax.json()
```

I get the following error: `Dajaxice: Something went wrong.` I have no idea where to look. What should I do?

Comment: Can you please explain more what is your goal what are you trying to do?
What do you have as input and  what do you want as output etc.

Comment: Basically, I want to rerender a part of my website wenn the button is clicked. I already know how to do that. But before doing that, I need to make this small example runnable.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what went wrong is that you're using the latest version of Django.

Djaxice is a dead project and stopped working after Django 1.6 was released, although the exact version when it broke doesn't appear to be documented. (This inference in [this Github issue](https://github.com/jorgebastida/django-dajaxice/issues/132) was the closest I could find to documenting exactly which version broke.)

I once tried upgrading Django in an existing project and found that it broke Djaxice. (This was a while back, so I don't remember what exactly the error was.)

Quoting from the [official Github repo](https://github.com/jorgebastida/django-dajaxice): "Should I use django-dajaxice? In a word, No."

Several people have tried to port Djaxice to newer versions of Django, but I've never seen a successful fork. (Maybe a new one was created since I last looked.) I've looked into porting it myself, but found it to be non-trivial.

Comment: What project is recommended now?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know of a direct replacement, so that might be a question deserving its own thread.

Comment: If my answer turned out to be the solution to your "Something went wrong" error, don't forget to mark it as accepted. - Thanks.