# How to post a search form using jQuery/Ajax and put results in a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, post

I'm trying to post a search query to a local server and return the results into a div using Ajax. I'm following the formula from the documentation but cannot get an output. Also not getting any console log errors. The source code is from: [Post a form using ajax and put results in a div](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

```
<form action="/" id="searchForm">
   <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search...">
   <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
  <!-- the result of the search will be rendered inside this div -->
<div id="result"></div>
<p id="content">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
</p>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#searchForm").submit(function(event) {

  // Stop form from submitting normally
  event.preventDefault();

  // Get some values from elements on the page:
  var $form = $(this),
    term = $form.find( "input[name='s']").val(),
    url = $form.attr("action");

  // Send the data using post
  var posting = $.post( url, {s: term});

  // Put the results in a div
  posting.done(function(data) {
    var content = $(data).find("#content");
    $("#result").empty().append(content);
  });
 });
});  
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Submitting HTML form using Jquery AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323360/submitting-html-form-using-jquery-ajax)

Comment: I'm assuming the version you're trying to run contains the full example code from the site which has the head elements which loads jQuery from CDN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `html()` method, i.e.:

```
var content = data;
console.log(data);
$("#result").html(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Code Specifically for you Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/U2h91ZFAqekoEeZpDNAx)

**JS**

```
// Code goes here
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#searchForm").submit(function(event) {
    // Stop form from submitting normally
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get some values from elements on the page:
    var $form = $(this),
      term = $form.find("input[name='s']").val(),
      url = $form.attr("action");

    // Send the data using post

    var posting = $.post(
      url, {
        s: term
      },
      myPostWasSuccessful,
      'html'
    );
  });
});

function myPostWasSuccessful(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  $("#result").html(data);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="/" id="searchForm">
    <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search...">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
  </form>
  <!-- the result of the search will be rendered inside this div -->
  <div id="result"></div>
  <p id="content">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

### [jQuery Post Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

We are using the `dataType` and `success` arguments to the `$.post` function.

> **success**
>
> *Type: Function( Object data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )*
>
> A callback function that is executed if the request succeeds. Required if dataType is provided, but can be null in that case.
>
> **dataType**
>
> *Type: String*
>
> The type of data expected from the server. Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, text, html).

Comment: I have a chunk of text in another php file. I'm trying query that text and return it into the html. The text is in a p tag like my code above. Can I do this or does my text have to be in XML/Json format?