# PHP not reciving data with AJAX's POST

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

I have to say I saw a dozens of topics similar to my problem, but most of them were typos or spelling.

My PHP file does not seem to receive any data from AJAX POST function (I'm getting Undefined Index). Here is my code:

```
var login = $("#log_l").val();
var pwd = $("#pwd_l").val();
alert(login);
alert(pwd);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'app/menu/login.php',
    data: {
        login1: login,
        pwd1: pwd,
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data == 'fail') {
            alert('test2');
            $('#failure_log').show();
        }
        else {
            document.location = " {$conf->action_root}postlogin";
        }
    }
});
return false;
```

And the login.php:

```
$login = $_POST['login1'];
$haslo = $_POST['pwd1'];
...
```

I tried with both:

```
login1:login,
pwd1:pwd,
```

And:

```
'login1':login,
'pwd1':pwd,
```

But in both ways I receive "Undefined index" error in .php file on 'login1' and 'pwd1' variables.
I checked that ajax 'reaches' file and it even receives the echos from .php file, but the variables are not sent/received.

Do you have any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure that you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors in the browser.. Only info "navigated to: ..."

Comment: Not the browser - the browser's developer tools.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST, $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])` and see what's arriving at the server.

Comment: Yes, sorry i ment the browser console.

Comment: @MarcB I'm getting: array(2){[login1]=>string(3)"log" ["pwd1"]=> string(3) "pwd".

Comment: So it does work somehow..

Comment: Set **login.php** to be `<?php echo '<pre>'.print_r($_POST, true).'</pre>'; ?>` and take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/21617685/2191572

Comment: Not related to the undefined index probably but unless your JS is being echoed out by PHP this doesn't look right: `document.location = " {$conf->action_root}postlogin";` You probably want something like `document.location = "<?= $conf->action_root; ?>postlogin";` ... if the JS **is** being echoed out by PHP there's a chance that `$.ajax` is causing a hiccup.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus If i did everything right it just shows that the content can't be displayed

Answer (score 0):

You need to use file_get_contents to capture ajax calls or you need to define. Check this

[How to get JSON data in php ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17295957/how-to-get-json-data-in-php)

Or

you need to set the ajax call as form_encoded_url
     contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",

refer this link
[Submitting HTML form using Jquery AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323360/submitting-html-form-using-jquery-ajax)