# how to checkbox value stored array when click checkbox using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name=options[cid]" value='1'     
onChange="chkdeptCount(this.value)" class="test">    
<input type="checkbox" name=options[cid]" value='2'     
onChange="chkdeptCount(this.value)" class="test">
```

**jquery:**

```
function chkdeptCount(val){    
$.ajax({ url: '../ajax/AjaxCall.php',
    data: {Action:'IMPLODEARRAY',arrVal: val},
    type: 'post',
    success: function(output) {
   alert(output);
    $('.result').html(output);
    }
    });

}
```

**PHP:**

```
if($_POST['Action']=='IMPLODEARRAY'){       
    $arr_val[] = $_POST['arrVal'];      
    print_r($arr_val);
}
```

When I run this code does not return array value. It returns a single value WHY?

Comment: Please add proper code, I can't read this.

Comment: What have you already tried to achieve the expected result? And why did'nt it work?

Comment: output is 1 then alert 2

Comment: `name=options[cid]"` missing quote, both checkbox having onchange event, and u are using `this` for getting current value

Comment: @shubhamkhatri You should not be altering the base example. As noted `name="options[cid]"` was not the in the OP. It was `name=options[cid]"` That may be the problem with the code. You should not edit the actual script, just the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

*Note that, you are missing the quote here `name=options[cid]"`.*

*And you are using `onChange="chkdeptCount(this.value)"` event with current value `this`, this will only return one value at once.*

**This is very basic Example:**

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post" id="formID" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="Action" value="IMPLODEARRAY">
<input type="checkbox" name="options[cid]" value='1' class="test">
<input type="checkbox" name="options[cid]" value='2' class="test">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="SubmitButton">
</form>
```

**AJAX:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#SubmitButton").click(function(){ // when submit button press
    var data = $("#formID").serialize(); // get all form input in serialize()
    $.ajax({
        url: YourURL, // add your url here
        type: "POST", // your method
        data: data, // your form data
        dataType: "json",  // you can use json/html type
        success: function(response) {
          console.log(response); // your response
        },
        beforeSend: function()
        {
            // if you want to display any loading message
        }
    });  // JQUERY Native Ajax End
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
if(count($_POST) > 0){ // if you have some value in AJAX request
  if($_POST['Action'] == 'IMPLODEARRAY'){ // your condition
    print_r($_POST['options']); // get all checkbox value.
  }
}
?>
```

*Few more example will help you to understand, you can you use: [Submitting HTML form using Jquery AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323360/submitting-html-form-using-jquery-ajax) | 
[jQuery AJAX submit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form)*