# How to submit not strongly typed html form in MVC using ajax or jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have below non strongly typed html view

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreateNonStronglyBlog";
}

<h2>Create Non Strongly Blog</h2>

@using (@Html.BeginForm("CreateBlog","blog")){
    @Html.Label("namelable", "Put your name here", new { @id = "name" })
    @Html.TextBox("txtname", "", new { @id = "txtName"})
    @Html.Label("urllable", "Put your Url here", new { @id = "url" })
    @Html.TextBox("txturl", "", new { @id = "txturl"})
    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

And below i have my controller actions to be call on submitting this form.

```
public ActionResult CreateBlog(Blog blg)
{
    topBlogs.Add(blg);
    return View("IndexNotStronglyTyped", topBlogs);
}
```

How to submit the form and send the values to controller's action method ?

Comment: You need to show your model for `Blog` (does it  really contain properties name `string txtname` and `txturl`?)

Comment: Also your form is missing a submit button

Comment: Yes that is correct.. i forgot to add that :)

Comment: The ModelBinding works based on input `name` attributes, which means that your `Blog` needs to have properties named `namelable`, `txtname`, `urllable` etc. What is the definition of Blog class?

Comment: I got below answer for my question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323360/submitting-html-form-using-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 1):

View

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreateNonStronglyBlog";
}

<h2>Create Non Strongly Blog</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateBlog","blog")){
    @Html.Label("namelable", "Put your name here", new { @id = "name" })
    @Html.TextBox("txtname", "", new { @id = "txtName"})
    @Html.Label("urllable", "Put your Url here", new { @id = "url" })
    @Html.TextBox("txturl", "", new { @id = "txturl"})
    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

Controller

```
Public ActionResult CreateBlog(blog model)
{
    //You will get all values in model
}
```

Note : `All your textbox names should match your model Property names, otherwise you won't get value of that textBox`

Answer (score 0):

declare begin form and model like this

```
@model yourmodelname
    using (@Html.BeginForm("CreateBlog", "controllername")){
    example ==> "@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.ID);"

<input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
    }

    public ActionResult CreateBlog(yourmodelname model)
        {
               example==>int woNumber = model.ID;

        }
```

Comment: But I want to send entire Blog model instead of sending each property seperately.

Comment: AFAIK the correct `BeginForm` statement is `@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateBlog", "controllername", FormMethod.Post)) { ... }` (note `@` placement)

Comment: And the name of the 2nd input is `txturl`, not `namelable`!

Comment: other wise create a model declare all parameters and then use model like

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult CreateBlog(FormCollection form)
    {
       // Access via form["namelable"],form["namelable"] etc..          
    }
```

Here FormCollection  will have all posted data to action ..

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult CreateBlog()
    {
       //Access via Request["txtName"],Request["txturl"]           
    }
or

public ActionResult CreateBlog(string txtName, string txturl)
    {
       //We will get submitted texbox values in given paramers           
    }
```

Comment: Please add explanations.