# How to stop the form from resetting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to stop the form from resetting to it's default value?

I've already tried the AJAX way, but it seems that there is an error to it. Even though that I have the code already, it seems that it is not working, neither the console log is displaying any errors.

This is my form:

```
    <form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="thisisform">
        <select name="account-type">
            <option value="teacher">Teacher</option>
            <option value="student">Student</option>
        </select> <br>
        <h3>Select by:</h3>
        <div id="selection">
            <input type="radio" name="selection" id="byAll" value="selectAll" checked> Select All <br>
            <input type="radio" name="selection" id="byVal" value="selectValue"> Select by Value <br><br>
        </div>
        <div id="selectNow" style="display:none;">
            <select name="search-type">
                <option value="username">Username</option>
                <option value="firstname">First Name</option>
                <option value="surname">Last Name</option>
                <option value="id">ID</option>
                <input type="text" name="searchVal" placeholder="Search now by the value" class="form-control"><br>
            </select>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Search and Delete" class="btn btn-primary">
    </form>
```

This is the script:

```
<script>        
    $('#selection').click(function() {
      if($('#byVal').is(':checked')) {
        $('#selectNow').slideDown("fast");
      }
      if($('#byAll').is(':checked')) {
        $('#selectNow').slideUp("fast");
      }
    });
    $("#thisisform").submit( function(e) {
      loadAjax();
      e.returnValue = false;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Submitting HTML form using Jquery AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323360/submitting-html-form-using-jquery-ajax)

Comment: Try this                                                                   $("#Formid").submit(function(event){
   loadAjax();
   event.preventDefault();
})

Answer (score 1):

Stop the form from submitting by using e.preventDefault();

```
   $("#thisisform").submit( function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); // added code
      loadAjax();
      e.returnValue = false;
    });
```

Comment: `loadAjax is not defined` error is present at the console log and the form is cannot be submitted.

Comment: yes I knew loadAjax() was not defined - but the point of the post was to prevent the form from submitting - your code should have the loadAjax() function - and if not - delete  that line.

Comment: Well, I deleted it now and now I cannot submit the form

Comment: Sorry - I should have been more clear - if you are atempting to submit the form via AJAX - then you need to prevent the form submission and then you deal with the form values via serializing the inputs. If you are not submitting the form via AJAX then you will need to remove the e.preventDefault() and let the form submit as a normal form.

Comment: Sorry for not clearing my question, but my question is that you can submit your form, but the form inputs (like Select, Checkboxes, Radio Inputs) should stay where they are at the last time, and not to be reset on their default values.

Comment: Using ajax Yes, using regular submit No, since the page will be refreshed and the form reset, else you may have to store the values in localStorage/cookies and charge them after the submission/refresh.