# how to create a contact form that submits information staying in the current page

Tags: php, html, css

I want to create a contact or information form that submits information whilst staying on the current page.

I am using a contact form on my website http://www.purpaldzinz.net/. It is basically for contacting us for our various services like SEO, social media, website designing.

Once you fill in and submit it, it leads you to a separate page using PHP.

I want a form that also submits the information but remains on the same page i.e. my home page whilst also displays confirmation messages like, `your message or information has been submitted` etc.

Comment: I tried to create a simple php based form which works fine, although most of the times I try to make changes, even minor ones, I run into some kind of problems - like it gives an error page or something like that.

And when filled it leads you to a Thank You page which I created.

Comment: This is the form I am using.

<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = $_POST['email']; 
    $to = 'mailID'; 
    $subject = 'Subject Title';
   
    $body = "From: $name\n Mobile: $mobile\ n Message:\n $Enquiry";
    
    if ($_POST['submit']) {     
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
header('Location: thanksforseo.html');
exit();
            ;
            ;
 } 
    } 
die();
?>

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link it may be helpful for you: https://www.formget.com/submit-form-using-ajax-php-and-jquery/

You can also find helpful details from this url : [Submitting HTML form using Jquery AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323360/submitting-html-form-using-jquery-ajax)

Comment: Thanks Sumesh for the useful resources. Will check them out and let you know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So you want a contact form, displaying a message telling you it has been submitted, without it refreshing?

Using HTML, PHP and just a tiny bit of jQuery, this should do it:

```js
$("#contactForm").submit(function() {
   return false;
});
```

```css
input[type=text], textarea {
 padding: 3px;
 width: 300px;
}
```

```html
    <?php
    if(!empty($_POST["name"]) && !empty($_POST["message"]) && !empty($_POST["category"])) {
     if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
     echo "Your message has been sent. Thank you for contacting us!";
     }    
    }
    else {
     echo "Please fill in all the fields";    
    }
?>
 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" id="contactForm">
 <select name="category" action="">
  <option>- Choose an item -</option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
 </select> 
 <br /> <br />
 <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" /> 
 <br /> <br />
 <textarea name="message" placeholer="Your message"></textarea> 
 <br /> <br />
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Xariez. This looks like well defined form, I will surely try this and let you know. Thanks again!