# Having separate ajax calls on a jsp calling to servlets

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have a button that is used for displaying an annual leave request by doing an ajax call to a servlet which then retrieves data in the response and displays it on the modal.
['view modal' buttons in a table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tdOe.png)

Once one of these buttons are clicked, they run a javascript function which does an ajax call and displays the data that recieved on the modal
[(Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbhED.png). Basically I need another ajax call to a servlet as and when the "respond to request" panel is clicked. I've heard of event binding which might be useful for solving my issue, however being the newbie I am, I haven't seen an example of how this works that I understand so maybe someone could attempt to provide one here for me.

The second ajax call is to basically running a query against the database to check whether or not the currently logged in user on my web app has already accepted/declined the request so that I can disable/remove the buttons without refreshing the page.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Two options for submitting different calls:

Each button submit different `form`, each `form` submit different action - [example with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323360/submitting-html-form-using-jquery-ajax)

Each button submit different `JavaScript` function the execute different ajax call 
- [example JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery)