# Prevent Bootstrap Model from Closing after Submit Button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to prevent my Modal window to close after I push submit Form button.

I tried a different kind of ways jquery/credform/javascript etc and nothing gave me the result I want.

Inside my Modal, as you can see I have a Form with different things. All fields are requested by my PHP server.

Please help me out with this. I want it after I push submit to remain open so the user that completes the form get's a message inside a box that I made there

```js
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
  this.modal('show');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">

          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

          <h4 class="modal-title">Comanda prin Email</h4>

        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">

          <?php include('forms.php'); ?>

            
<div class="container">

              <form id="contact" action="<?= htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) ?>" method="post">

                <div class=""><p style="text-align: center;">Dupa plasarea comenzi in maximum 24 ore ve-ti fi contactat Telefonic pentru confirmarea acesteia!!!</p></div>
                <fieldset>
                  <sup>*</sup>
                  <input placeholder="Nume Produs" type="text" name="numeprodus" value="<?= $numeprodus ?>" tabindex="1" autofocus>
                  <span class="error"><?= $numeprodus_error ?></span>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                  <sup>*</sup>
                  <input placeholder="Marimea" type="text" name="marime" value="<?= $marime_produs ?>" tabindex="2" autofocus>
                  <span class="error"><?= $marime_error ?></span>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>

                  <sup>*</sup>
                  <input placeholder="Numele" type="text" name="nume" value="<?= $nume ?>" tabindex="3" autofocus>

                  <span class="error"><?= $nume_error ?></span>

                </fieldset>

                <fieldset>
                  <sup>*</sup>
                  <input placeholder="Prenumele" type="text" name="prenume" value="<?= $prenume ?>" tabindex="4" autofocus>
                  <span class="error"><?= $prenume_error ?></span>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                  <sup>*</sup>
                  <input placeholder="Adresa" type="text" name="adresa" value="<?= $adresa ?>" tabindex="5" autofocus>
                  <span class="error"><?= $adresa_error ?></span>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                  <sup>*</sup>
                  <input placeholder="Oras" type="text" name="oras" value="<?= $oras ?>" tabindex="6" autofocus>
                  <span class="error"><?= $oras_error ?></span>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                  <sup>*</sup>
                  <input placeholder="Cod Postal" type="text" name="codpostal" value="<?= $codpostal ?>" tabindex="7" autofocus>
                  <span class="error"><?= $codpostal_error ?></span>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>

                  <sup>*</sup>
                  <input placeholder="Email" type="text" name="email" value="<?= $email ?>" tabindex="8">

                  <span class="error"><?= $email_error ?></span>

                </fieldset>

                <fieldset>

                  <sup>*</sup>
                  <input placeholder="Numar Telefon" type="text" name="telefon" value="<?= $telefon ?>" tabindex="9">

                  <span class="error"><?= $telefon_error ?></span>

                </fieldset>

                <fieldset>

                  <textarea value="<?= $message ?>" name="message" tabindex="10">

                  </textarea>

                </fieldset>

                <fieldset>
                    <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Submit</button>
                </fieldset>
                <div class="success"><?= $success ?></div>

              </form>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="dv-atentionare"><p class="dv-att-p1">Atentie!</p><p class="dv-att-p2">Aveti la dispozitie 48 ore de la plasarea comenzi pentru a o putea anula!</p></div>

        <div class="modal-footer">

         <input  class="btn btn-default">

         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You want to prevent modal closing and also prevent form submit?

Comment: I want only to prevent modal from closing, that's all.

Comment: When someone push submit. The form is send and a message should appear on the modal but my model closes up and my page goes at the top

Comment: That's because your page is posted back to server and is now reloaded. You have  two solutions for this. Let me edit it in my answer.

Comment: @AndreiCCL when you submit the form the page gets reloaded you cant prevent it from hidding. submit form using ajax then you can prevent your modal from hidding

Comment: I don't know how to do it :(. Have to read more idk

Comment: See my edited answer

Comment: My brain is dead now :)) . Can't make it work

Comment: Can you show me?

Comment: @AndreiCCL Did you try it using ajax ?

Comment: No, because I don't really know how to do it :(

Comment: i have done it here https://fiddle.jshell.net/marwat/735yvkb0/

Comment: i have submitted the form using jquery ajax. you can customize according to your requirments.

Comment: Now when I load the page it opens the form automatically and I want it to open on a button press that I already installed in my HTML file.   And still when I press submit or even click the fields. the modal dissapears

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so there are two solutions for this.

1. Use JQuery AJAX to submit form, and prevent default form behaviour. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323360/submitting-html-form-using-jquery-ajax)
2. Reopen the Modal, when form is returned from server. I might not be able to give you any `PHP` code for this but I have done this in `Asp.Net MVC.`

When you post your data to `PHP`, return some flag from there. Then you can use that flag to turn following script on/off.

```
// PHP if($some_flag == true)
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
    })
</script>
// PHP endif
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs `data-dismiss="modal"` is to dismiss the modal when the button is clicked.

Removing this attribute should stop the modal from closing when the button is clicked.

Comment: You should also send the form via ajax. Without sending it via ajax, it is going to reload the page or redirect to a new page.