# PHP jQuery and Ajax sending / receiving variables & data

Tags: php, jquery

So within my jQuery I am making an AJAX call to set a cookie and use the same data to echo the result:

**jQuery**

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'script.php',
        data: {status: 'enabled'}
        });
```

**PHP**

```
if(!empty($_GET['status'])) {
   $value = $_GET['status'];
   echo $value;
   setcookie("status", $value, time()+3600, "/");
}
```

The confusing part is that the cookie is being set, however the value is not being echoed, i also tried to print it but doesnt work either.

Ultimately what I wish to do is use the data passed through the ajax call and assign it to a php variable to be used for some conditionals.

Am I missing something? I am learning how to program.

**update**
[image: request in network]

```
Request URL:http://localhost/wp-content/plugins/lu-ban/inc/lu_ban.php?status=enabled
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
```

Comment: Where do you expect the value to be echo'd _to_?

Comment: i guess the page, i just want to see if its being successfully passed on to php, which i think it is since the cookie is being set because the output is not empty

Comment: Then you need to modify your ajax call to handle the response. Try searching the jquery api docs for the `done()` function.

Comment: If you just want to know that the request was successful, you can open your browser's dev tools and look for the request on the network tab.

Comment: thanks for the hint jason, i can see the request but i cant interpret it. ill add a screenshot to the question

Comment: It looks like your `enabled` value was echo'd to the response, but you also have a php error. Try visiting `script.php?status=enabled` directly in your browser to start troubleshooting.

Comment: okay i see where the error is, ill fix it and be back

Comment: Since I am using wordpress functions, it seems that the file cant access these functions thats why it shows undefined, i may need to require_once the file in a particular way but i am searching for the proper solutions

Answer (score 1):

You need to see it in script then you need a success callback Here

```
jQuery.ajax({
   url: 'script.php',
   data: {status: 'enabled'},
   success: function(returnedData){
                  alert(returnedData)
            }  
});
```

Comment: `success:` in this construct is **NOT** deprecated. However, the preferred method is via use of the jqXHR object introduced in jQ1.4. When using the jqXHR object, **yes** `.success()` has been deprecated in favor of `.done()` and `.error()` deprecated in favor of `.fail()`

Comment: @JeffreyA. -- See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821141/deprecation-of-success-parameter-in-jquery-ajax -- As DevlshOne said, this use is not deprecated.

Comment: or the **.done callback** where you retrieve the data returned and utilize the same. refer to jquery documentation for more info

Answer (score 1):

Then you'll have to use your Web Developer's tools in your browser to trace the HTTP requests and examine the headers (for the data sent TO the script) and the Responses (for the data being returned).

From the [jQuery $.ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> The jQuery XMLHttpRequest (jqXHR) object returned by $.ajax() as of
>   jQuery 1.5 is a superset of the browser's native XMLHttpRequest
>   object. For example, it contains responseText and responseXML
>   properties, as well as a getResponseHeader() method.