# Ajax MVC hide button in a table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdownlist in table and button that should show if there is a value form the database.  In my dropdown I send to a function

```
onchange = "getInfoid(this)"
```

The function:

```
function getInfoid(myvalue) {
        var typeid = $(myvalue).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/mycontroller/GetInfoUrl',
            contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
            type: 'Get',
            data: {
                id: typeid
            },
            dataType: 'html'
        })
            .success(function (result) {
                var tr = $($(myvalue).parents("tr")[0]);
                var button = tr.find("button#Details0");
                $(button).attr("onclick", "viewOhaInfo('" + result + "')");
                $(button).show();
            })
            .error(function (result) {
             var tr = $($(myvalue).parents("tr")[0]);
             tr.find("button#Details0").hide();
            });
    };
```

The script does not show or hide the button.  To test it; I tried the Ajax script to show and hide a div, and tried hiding and showing the button in the table using the same without Ajax, both worked.  Do I lose the value of myvalue variable or what else could be the reason.

**EDIT**
The problem was in my understanding of success and error, I changed my script to:

```
 .success(function (data) {
               if (data == null) {
                   var tr = $($(myvalue).parents("tr")[0]);
                   tr.find("button#Details0").hide();
               } else {

                   var tr = $($(myvalue).parents("tr")[0]);
                   var button = tr.find("button#Details0");
                   $(button).attr("onclick", "viewOhaInfo('" + data + "')");
                   $(button).show();
               }
```

This solved it.  Thank you all for your assistance.

Comment: no idea what you are asking or what your issue is

Comment: Good point, I edited the question.  The script does not show or hide the button. Thanks

Comment: you probably need to look into the console to see if there are any error

Comment: can only be one element with that ID in the page. ID's must be unique by definition, so that might be your problem. `$("#Details0").hide()` should work when there is only one of that ID. otherwise use class instead of ID

Comment: I tried unique ID but it did not work.  Thanks

Comment: Most likely your selectors are not correct. You need to show the html for a row of the table.

Answer (score 0):

jqXHR.success() and jqXHR.error() are deprecated. Read api [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

> jqXHR.done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {}); An alternative
>   construct to the success callback option, the .done() method replaces
>   the deprecated jqXHR.success() method. Refer to deferred.done() for
>   implementation details.
>
> jqXHR.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {}); An
>   alternative construct to the error callback option, the .fail() method
>   replaces the deprecated .error() method. Refer to deferred.fail() for
>   implementation details.

so modify your script to this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/mycontroller/GetInfoUrl',
        contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'Get',
        data: {
            id: typeid
        },
        dataType: 'html'
    })
        .done(function (result) {
            var tr = $($(myvalue).parents("tr")[0]);
            var button = tr.find("button#Details0");
            $(button).attr("onclick", "viewOhaInfo('" + result + "')");
            $(button).show();
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
         var tr = $($(myvalue).parents("tr")[0]);
         tr.find("button#Details0").hide();
        });
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821141/deprecation-of-success-parameter-in-jquery-ajax) is how to do it alternatively.