# ajax beforeSend doesn't execute according to flow

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$('.item').click(function(){
myFunc();
});

function myFunc(){
$.ajax({
success: function (data) { //call API },
beforeSend: function() {  $('.loading').css({'display':'block!important'}); },
complete: function () { $('.loading').css({'display':'none !important'});},
})
}
```

my code within `beforeSend` doesn't work, the success came first. This is strange, it should be `beforeSend` execute first. I try to put an `alert()` before showing my loading, the loading did appear. What's wrong here?

Comment: did you try to add a alert in the before send handler and see whether it is really getting executed...

Comment: How do you know that `success` is being called first? Please show us how you are determining that.

Comment: @ArunPJohny beforeSend handler is perfectly fine. I put alert there, not only the alert got triggered, but the loader display block is triggered.

Comment: @JLRishe because I can see the result of the success's data callback, but the loading is not showing

Comment: Well aside from the commented out `},` and the lack of a `url` parameter, there's nothing discernably wrong with the code you have shown us. Can you show us your actual code?

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFunc{
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://abcd.com",
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('.loading').css({'display':'block!important'});
        }
    })
    .done(function(data){
        //Call API
        $('.loading').css({'display':'none !important'});
    })
}
```

Comment: `success: function(){ ... }` is not deprecated according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821141/deprecation-of-success-parameter-in-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

You are commenting out `},`

```
success: function (data) { //call API },
//                                    ^ this is commented out
```

and

```
beforeSend: function() {  $('.loading').css({'display':'block!important'})
//                                     You need a space here ^
```

Comment: don't think that is the problem... OP is saying the success is working so there is no syntax issue the commented code should have caused a syntax error

Comment: @ArunPJohny I think the second part of the answer might solve his problem

Answer (score 0):

Jason Please Update your script

```
 $('.item').click(function(){
    myFunc();
    });

    function myFunc(){
    $.ajax({
    success: function (data) { 
   //call API 
   },
    beforeSend: function() {  $('.loading').css({'display':'block!important'});
alert("Before Send Function Call");
 },
    complete: function () { $('.loading').css({'display':'none !important'});},
    })
    }
```

Comment: add an alert? are you kidding me?

Comment: It's not place for kidding!Your issue is that line of code success: function (data) { //call API }, I just add alert because you can check the beforeSend function execute proper youo can also add console to check what type of data your getting in success message.

Answer (score 0):

My idea is, make  visible loading div before Ajax call. Again  Make it invisible in success block.Sample code below. Hope it solve your issue.

```
$('.item').click(function(){
    myFunc();
    });

    function myFunc(){
    // before calling ajax make it visible
    $('.loading').css({'display':'block!important'});
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"http://example.com/api/responce.php",
        data:{"u_email":email,"u_pwd":pass},
    }).success(function(res){
      // make it invisible
      $('.loading').css({'display':'none!important'});
      //do whatever with the responce from api
    }).error(function()(
      //handle ajax error if any
    ));
```