# Trying to understand DRY principles in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, backbone.js, dry

I am currently trying to sharpen my refactoring skills, I have a block of code that I have written that has two methods that are very similar, and I am trying to wrap my head around simplifying my bloated code, any suggestions would be welcome.

As you can see the two methods are very similar, and the only real difference is the URL the POST to.

```
authenticateA : function( e ) {
  var $this = $( e.target ).closest( '[data-fn]' )
  ,   text = $this.text()
  ,   that = this;

  $this.text( 'Authenticating...' ).addClass("auth-button-disable")

  $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : '/A_authentications/update/',
    data : { _method : 'PUT', sms_token : this.$el.find( '#sms-input' ).val() },
    complete: function( xhr ) {

      if ( xhr.status === 200 )
        that.relocate();
      else {
        $this.text( text ).removeClass("auth-button-disable");
        that.handleError( xhr.status );
      }
    },
    dataType : 'json'
  });
},

authenticateB : function( e ) {
  var $this = $( e.target ).closest( '[data-fn]' )
  ,   text = $this.text()
  ,   that = this;

  $this.text( 'Authenticating...' ).addClass("auth-button-disable")

  $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : '/B_authentications/',
    data : { otp : this.$el.find( '#B-input' ).val() },
    complete: function( xhr ) {
      if ( xhr.status === 200 )
        that.relocate();
      else {
        $this.text( text ).removeClass("auth-button-disable");
        that.handleError( xhr.status )
      }
    },
    dataType : 'json'
  });
}
```

I call the methods as click functions in an events block:

```
'click [data-fn="authenticate-A"]' : 'authenticateA',
'click [data-fn="authenticate-B"]' : 'authenticateB'
```

I think these could be refactored into one method or two slimmer methods, I'm just not sure where to start, thanks again in advance.

Comment: The key to refactoring two methods into one is to determine what are the differences between the two and could those differences be specified in either a function parameter or from a dom element. As a starting point it seems the url and the type are different, these values can come from the <form> tag itself which you can then retrieve using jquery.

Comment: using ajax `complete` method with the `200` is redundant. just use the `done` method instead. also the `complete` method is deprecated.

Comment: The use of the `complete` parameter [is not deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15821199/2788131). `$.ajax({}).complete()`, the method, is.

Comment: This question is too broad. As you can see, there are various ways of doing it. I think this is a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a function that generates those functions:

```
generateAuthFunction : function( authDetails) {
  return function (e) {
    var $this = $( e.target ).closest( '[data-fn]' )
    ,   text = $this.text()
    ,   that = this;

    $this.text( 'Authenticating...' ).addClass("auth-button-disable")

    $.ajax({
      type : 'POST',
      url : authDetails.url,
      data : authDetails.dataFunc(this),
      complete: function( xhr ) {

        if ( xhr.status === 200 )
          that.relocate();
        else {
          $this.text( text ).removeClass("auth-button-disable");
          that.handleError( xhr.status );
        }
      },
      dataType : 'json'
    });
  };
}
```

Then you generate it with:

```
var authDetailsA = {
  url :  '/A_authentications/update/',
  dataFunc : function (this) {
    return { _method : 'PUT', sms_token : this.$el.find( '#sms-input' ).val() };
  }
};
var authDetailsB = {
  url :  '/B_authentications/',
  dataFunc : function (this) {
    return { otp : this.$el.find( '#B-input' ).val() };
};
authenticateA : generateAuthFunction(authDetailsA);
authenticateB : generateAuthFunction(authDetailsB);
```

You could call it like before:

```
'click [data-fn="authenticate-A"]' : 'authenticateA',
'click [data-fn="authenticate-B"]' : 'authenticateB'
```

I think this might even introduce unnecessary complexity, but it is more DRY.

Comment: Even in a backbone view?  Where do you call the generator functions?

Comment: You could call it where you defined the authenticateA and authenticateB functions before. If you replace your definition of the functions with the first two code blocks, it would have the same effect, authenticateA and authenticateB would be defined as before.

Comment: Ah, I see. I guess where I am getting  hung up is where to put the var authDetails blocks in relation to the  return Backbone.View.extend block that all the other code is in.

Answer (score 2):

1. Abstract away your requests. Mixing your app logic into your views can only muddle the picture. Let's create an `Authentication` module:

   ```
   var Authentication = (function(Backbone, _) {
       function whoGoesThere(opts) {
           opts = _.extend({}, opts, {
               type : 'POST',
               dataType: 'json'
           });

           return Backbone.$.ajax(opts);
       }

       return {
           A: function(data) {
               data = _.extend({}, data, {
                    _method : 'PUT'
               });
               return whoGoesThere({
                   url : '/A_authentications/update/',
                   data: data            
               });
           },
           B: function(data) {
               return whoGoesThere({
                   url : '/B_authentications/',
                   data: data            
               });
           }
       };
   })(Backbone, _);
   ```
2. Configure your views to handle the events with a function instead of a function name, pass your values to the appropriate method on the previous module and then delegate the returned promise to a common handler:

   ```
   events: {
       'click [data-fn="authenticate-A"]': function(e) {
           var promise = Authentication.A({
               sms_token : this.$el.find( '#sms-input' ).val()
           });
           this.onAuthentication(e, promise);
       },
       'click [data-fn="authenticate-B"]': function(e) {
           var promise = Authentication.B({
               otp : this.$el.find( '#B-input' ).val()
           });
           this.onAuthentication(e, promise);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Handle the promise  (here the Ajax object but that could be anything)

   ```
   onAuthentication: function(e, promise) {
       var $this = $(e.target).closest('[data-fn]')
       ,   text = $this.text()
       ,   that = this;

       $this.text( 'Authenticating...' ).addClass("auth-button-disable");

       promise.done(function() {
           that.relocate();
       });
       promise.fail(function(xhr) {
           that.handleError(xhr.status);
       });
       promise.always(function() {
           $this.text(text).removeClass("auth-button-disable");        
       });
   }
   ```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/s3ydy3u6/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try (untested code):

```
authenticate: function(t, e) { // t = 'A' || 'B'
  var $this = $( e.target ).closest( '[data-fn]' )
  ,   text = $this.text()
  ,   that = this
  ,   url
  ,   data;

  $this.text( 'Authenticating...' ).addClass("auth-button-disable")
  
  // conditionally set up your variables
  if(t == 'A') {
      data = { _method : 'PUT', sms_token : this.$el.find( '#sms-input' ).val() }; 
      url = '/A_authentications/update/';
  } else if(t == 'B') {
      url = '/B_authentications/';
      data = { otp : this.$el.find( '#B-input' ).val() };
  }
    
  $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : url, // use them
    data : data, // use them
    complete: function( xhr ) {

      if ( xhr.status === 200 )
        that.relocate();
      else {
        $this.text( text ).removeClass("auth-button-disable");
        that.handleError( xhr.status );
      }
    },
    dataType : 'json'
  });
},
```

Comment: How would you call the click events?

Answer (score 1):

You can just check the data-fn attribute in the authenticate function.

```
authenticate: function (e) {        
        var $this = $(e.target).closest('[data-fn]'),
            text = $this.text(),
            that = this;
        $this.text('Authenticating...').addClass("auth-button-disable");
        var fn = $this.data("fn");

        switch (fn) {
            case "authenticate-A":
                data = {
                    _method: 'PUT',
                    sms_token: this.$el.find('#sms-input').val()
                };
                url = '/A_authentications/update/';
                break;
            case "authenticate-B":
                data = {
                    otp: this.$el.find('#B-input').val()
                };
                url = '/B_authentications/update/';
                break;

        }

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: data,
            complete: function (xhr) {

                if (xhr.status === 200) that.relocate();
                else {
                    $this.text(text).removeClass("auth-button-disable");
                    that.handleError(xhr.status);
                }
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        });


    }
```