# x-editable post value is undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, x-editable

I just created an x-editable form :

```
   <a href='#' class='username'
   data-pk='<?php echo $key['idca']; ?>'
   data-type="text"
   data-placement="right"> <?php echo $key['categoryname']; ?> </a>
```

Then I created Javascript function to handle x-editable form :

```
    $.fn.editable.defaults.success = function() { $(this).show() };
    $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
    $('.username').editable({
        url:'edit.php',
        pk:'1',
        type:'text',
        send:'always',
        ajaxOptions:{
            dataType:'json'
        },
        success: function(response, newValue) {
            window.alert('oke');
        },
        error: function(response, newValue) {
            window.alert('failed');
        }
    });
```

and in PHP I just create as follow :

```
<?php

 $pk = $_POST['pk'];
 $val = $_POST['value'];
 $name = $_POST['name'];

 print_r($_POST);

 ?>
```

But why I received message "undefined index pk, value, name" on window alert, which means I failed posting pk, value, name from x-editable..

Need helps, thank you very much

Comment: The `$.ajax({}).success()` method [is deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15821199/2788131). Use `success` parameter or `.done()` method instead. Why aren't you `echo`ing your variable so `msg` actually returns something? Also, why aren't you passing any object to `$('.username').editable({});`, such as `url:` for instance. You don't have to do the Ajax call by yourself when using this plugin.

Comment: Sorry, I'm indeed using done function, it showed the same message as success

Comment: D4V1D is right, pass pk, url, title inside editable() and check. Here is the [doc](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Given the following HTML

```
<a href="#" class="username"
    data-pk="<?php echo $key['idca']; ?>"
    data-type="text"
    data-placement="right"
>
    <?php echo $key['categoryname']; ?>
</a>
```

You can use this jQuery:

```
$.fn.editable.defaults.success = function() { $(this).show() };
$('#username').editable({
    type: 'text',  // optionnal if you've set up the data-type attribute 
    pk: $(this).data('pk'), // optionnal if you've set up the data-pk attribute 
    url: 'edit.php', // mandatory
    title: 'Enter username'
});
```

This should work [as per the documentation](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html). There is no need for you to do the `$.ajax({});` by yourself.

Comment: where can I echo PHP message after the form has been submitted?

Comment: PHP response of submitted data using AJAX. It shows nothing after I click submit button

Comment: You mean the new value is not displayed?

Comment: yes, there was no response from PHP side. Nothing happened.

Comment: I'll provide you with a snippet of code that'll hopefully do it as I faced the same problem. Are you sure the Ajax request is made?

Comment: yes, I'm sure. I added ajaxOptions function and set 'send' to 'always'. Please provide me.

Comment: should I use ajaxOptions in $('.username').editable({}) ? If not so, where PHP response will be shown? I've tried. Nothing happened.

Comment: I edited my question with posting whole x-editable and php script.

Answer (score 0):

A little late but on php side when you response you should use json_encode because x-editable is expecting you to return with json string.

```
 $pk = $_POST['pk'];
 $val = $_POST['value'];
 $name = $_POST['name'];

 echo json_encode($_POST);
 die();
```