# No alert from Ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I´m trying to alert some data from a Ajax call. Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?

**PHP**

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    echo json_encode($row);
}
echo "Done!";
```

**Result from Json_encode / Network Preview**

```
{"flakId":"21098-10_flak-2"}{"flakId":"21098-10_flak-1"}Done!
```

**JS**

```
if(chosenObjNr){
    alert('I CAN see this alert')
    $.ajax({
        url:'php/update.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'chosenObjNr=' + chosenObjNr,
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function (data){ alert("failed, i can see this!");},             
        success: function(data){  

            alert('I cannot see this alert!');
            alert(data);

            var data0;
            data0 = data[0];
            alert(data0);

            var falkId;
            flakId = data[0];
            alert(flakId);

            console.log(data);
        }

    });

};
```

**RESULT**

No alert and nothing in the console.

Comment: you need to show more of your code

Comment: Tell me what you need? The rest of code is working properly. I cant see how it matter!

Comment: you are giving small snippets, need to see more of the surrounding code like the rest of the JS for the AJAX call

Comment: I can echo Json_encode($row)... so my ajax call works. But not the fetch of  succes?!

Comment: Also, it would be good to see what's going on in the PHP side. If nothing is being alerted, that most probably means nothing is being returned in your PHP code. can you just run a simple `echo "I am here";` in your PHP and let us know if it gets returned?

Comment: @Sina As you can se in **Network Preview"  i have result from Json encoded echo. My php is nothing wrong

Comment: ah I see. Then can you add up `error: function (data){ alert("failed!");}` to your ajax call and let us know what you see?

Comment: @Sina See updated script. I CAN see and i CANNOT see this alert!

Comment: Have you tried this with `async: false` out of curiosity?

Comment: wait now I am confused :( you get the "failed" alert that I added? did you even try it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that the `success` part of the ajax never will run. You defined the `dataType` as a json, so it expecting json. Your PHP is echos 2 json and an unwanted string.

So, to check what is your error add the `fail` function as Sina sad in the comment:

```
if (chosenObjNr) {
alert('I CAN see this alert')
$.ajax({
    url: 'php/update.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'chosenObjNr=' + chosenObjNr,
    dataType: 'json',
}).done(function (data) {
    alert('I cannot see this alert!');
    //Do what you want to do here
}).fail(function (msg) {
    alert('An error occured: ' + msg.statusText);
});
```

}

And, if you want to fix your `.php` remove the `echo 'Done';` part, and add your records to an array, and when its done, encode it to json:

```
$return = array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $return[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($return);
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. How do i alert the first data in the array? tried: alert(data[0]); with no success. It says: [object object]

Comment: Use no alert, use `console.log(data);` You can itareate it on the data like `$.each(data, function(index, object) { console.log(object) });`

Comment: Just as a side note here and to make sure people are not confused, the `success` is not deprecated in the way the OP is using it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821141/deprecation-of-success-parameter-in-jquery-ajax

Comment: @Rasclatt Thank you for the correction. I removed that part from my answer.