# No data receive in Jquery from php json_encode

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I need help for my code as i have been browsing the internet looking for the answer for my problem but still can get the answer that can solve my problem. I am kind of new using AJAX. I want to display data from json_encode in php file to my AJAX so that the AJAX can pass it to the textbox in the HTML.

My problem is Json_encode in php file have data from the query in json format but when i pass it to ajax success, function(users) is empty. Console.log also empty array. I have tried use JSON.parse but still i got something wrong in my code as the users itself is empty. Please any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

car_detail.js

```
    $(document).ready(function() {


        function $_GET(q,s) {
            s = (s) ? s : window.location.search;
            var re = new RegExp('&amp;'+q+'=([^&amp;]*)','i');
            return (s=s.replace(/^\?/,'&amp;').match(re)) ?s=s[1] :s='';
        }
            var car_rent_id1 = $_GET('car_rent_id');
            car_rent_id.value = car_rent_id1;

                    $.ajax({  
        type: 'POST',
        url: "http://localhost/ProjekCordova/mobile_Rentacar/www/php/car_detail.php",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false, 
        data: { car_rent_id: this.car_rent_id1 },
        success:  function(users) {

        console.log(users);
        $('#car_name').val(users.car_name); 

        }
    });
    });
```

car_detail.php

```
    $car_rent_id = $_GET['car_rent_id'];   
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT c.car_name, c.car_type, c.car_colour, 
    c.plate_no, c.rate_car_hour, c.rate_car_day, c.car_status, 
    r.pickup_location
    FROM car_rent c
    JOIN rental r ON c.car_rent_id=r.car_rent_id
    WHERE c.car_rent_id = $car_rent_id");

    $users = array();
      while($r = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $user = array(
        "car_name" => $r['car_name'], 
        "car_type" => $r['car_type'], 
        "car_colour" => $r['car_colour'], 
        "plate_no" => $r['plate_no'], 
        "rate_car_hour" => $r['rate_car_hour'], 
        "rate_car_day" => $r['rate_car_day'], 
        "car_status" => $r['car_status'], 
        "pickup_location" => $r['pickup_location']
        );
         $users[] = $user;
    // print_r($r);die;
    }
    print_r(json_encode($users)); //[{"car_name":"Saga","car_type":"Proton","car_colour":"Merah","plate_no":"WA2920C","rate_car_hour":"8","rate_car_day":"0","car_status":"","pickup_location":""}]
```

car_detail.html

```
  <label>ID:</label>
                <input type="text" name="car_rent_id" id="car_rent_id"><br>

                <label>Car Name:</label>
                <div class = "input-group input-group-sm">
                    <span class = "input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon3"></span>
                    <input type = "text" name="car_name" id="car_name" class = "form-control" placeholder = "Car Name" aria-describedby = "sizing-addon3">
                </div></br>

                <label>Car Type:</label>
                <div class = "input-group input-group-sm">
                    <span class = "input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon3"></span>
                    <input type = "text" name="car_type" id="car_type" class = "form-control" placeholder = "Car Type" aria-describedby = "sizing-addon3">
                </div></br>
```

Comment: Duplicating this line `data: { car_rent_id: this.car_rent_id1 },` wont help!

Comment: Also, you've got `);` after your `success()` method that doesn't look like it should be there.

Comment: You forgot to close the `$.ajax()`, your code is full of syntax errors

Comment: @RiggsFolly. Thank you for the reply. Actually i have use that line to get an id from the url, pass to the php to make a query. I am using GET method for that purpose. Then the query value will pass back to the json to be display in the textbox in html. Is my way wrong?

Comment: Yes, but you dont need TWO OF THEM

Comment: i have not copied my code properly. Sorry.

Comment: @AravindhGopi. In php file i have put the content type properly. Actually only this function i have got problem as other registration process, and display data in table i have succeed.

Comment: If you navigate directly to the PHP file, do you get an error message or does it correctly output the JSON?

Comment: @pendo.. this is the output from car_detail.php print_r(json_encode($users)); [{"car_name":"Saga","car_type":"Proton","car_colour":"Merah","plate_no":"WA2920C","rate_car_hour":"8","rate_car_day":"0","car_status":"","pickup_location":""}]

Comment: Looks like your js is malformed, please see my code skeleton below.  If it's still not work once you're using the non-deprecated code, let us know and update your code in the question.

Comment: where is this `car_rent_id` defined?

Comment: @julekgwa.. car_rent_id is from the function $_GET in the js file where it search in the url from the previous page.

Comment: Your JSON is malformed.  Run it in a tester here: https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: shouldn't it be `var car_rent_id`?

Comment: if i use var car_rent_id instead of var car_rent_id1, the id does not display in the form for me to use it in the php query.

Comment: you don't even use that variable, where do you use it?

Comment: @Luqman305 learn to accept answers, I have seen your passed questions you don't accept answers, when you feel that an answer has solved your problem, accept it as it will help other people in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `this` in `this.car_rent_id1` and `cache: false` this works with `HEAD` and `GET`, in your AJAX you are using `POST` but in your PHP you use `$_GET`. And `car_rent_id` is not defined, your function `$_GET(q,s)` requires two parameters and only one is passed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function $_GET(q,s) {
        s = (s) ? s : window.location.search;
        var re = new RegExp('&amp;'+q+'=([^&amp;]*)','i');
        return (s=s.replace(/^\?/,'&amp;').match(re)) ?s=s[1] :s='';
    }
    var car_rent_id1 = $_GET('car_rent_id'); // missing parameter
    car_rent_id.value = car_rent_id1; // where was this declared?

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "http://localhost/ProjekCordova/mobile_Rentacar/www/php/car_detail.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { car_rent_id: car_rent_id1 },
        success:  function(users) {
            console.log(users);
            $('#car_name').val(users.car_name);
        }
    });
});
```

You can also use [$.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/), post is just a shorthand for `$.ajax()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function $_GET(q,s) {
        s = (s) ? s : window.location.search;
        var re = new RegExp('&amp;'+q+'=([^&amp;]*)','i');
        return (s=s.replace(/^\?/,'&amp;').match(re)) ?s=s[1] :s='';
    }
    var car_rent_id1 = $_GET('car_rent_id');
    car_rent_id.value = car_rent_id1;

    $.post('http://localhost/ProjekCordova/mobile_Rentacar/www/php/car_detail.php', { car_rent_id: car_rent_id1 }, function (users) {
        console.log(users);
        $('#car_name').val(users.car_name);
    });
});
```

and in your `PHP` change

```
$car_rent_id = $_GET['car_rent_id'];
```

to

```
$car_rent_id = $_POST['car_rent_id'];
```

Comment: thankssss!!! I have change according to your suggestion and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code skeleton using .done/.fail/.always

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
$(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'theurl',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false
  }).done(function(data){
    console.log(data);
  }).fail(function(data){
    console.log(data);
  }).always(function(data){
    console.log(data);
  });
});
</script>
```

I've adapted your code, so you can see the error, replace the ajax call with this one

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
      url: "theurl",
      dataType: "json",
      data: { car_rent_id: car_rent_id1 },
      success: function(users) {
        console.log(users);
        $('#car_name').val(users.car_name);
      },
      error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert("I failed, even though the server is giving a 200 response header, I can't read your json.");
      }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: There's difference between `$.ajax({}).success(function(){...});` and `$.ajax({success: fun...})`

Comment: Thank you. I'm aware of that.  I'm giving him the non-deprecated code skeleton to build from.

Comment: I just googled this and you're correct.  Thank you.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821141/deprecation-of-success-parameter-in-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 0):

A couple of recommendations on this, I would follow jQuery API to try an see where the request is failing http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/. Also, I would access the ids for the input fileds with jQuery. e.g.: `$("#theID").val()`.