# Ajax request not firing in new version of jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a small script that checks the username in the database if it is taken it will say taken if its available it will say available. currently the below code works perfectly in jQuery v1.7.2

How ever I need to update it to work with the current version of jQuery v3.2.1,
but trying to use the current jquery version it just says checking availability and nothing else.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#username").keyup(function() {
    var username = $("#username").val();
    var msgbox = $("#status");

    if (username.length > 3) {
      $("#status").html('');

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "includes/user_check.php",
        data: "username=" + username,
        success: function(msg) {
          $("#status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request) {
            if (msg == 'OK') {

              $("#username").removeClass("red");
              $("#username").addClass("green");
              msgbox.html('Available');
            } else {
              $("#username").removeClass("green");
              $("#username").addClass("red");
              msgbox.html(msg);
            }

          });
        }
      });
    } else {
      $("#username").addClass("red");
      $("#status").html('<font color="#cc0000">To Short</font>');
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you rephrase your question ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Rephrase? I am simply explaining the best of my ability

Comment: Which version works and which fails ?

Comment: @Gaby aka G. Petrioli I just updated the question I am using jquery 3.2.1 but it just says checking. but with version Jquery 1.7.2 it works fine

Comment: @epic see https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#ajax for why `success` is not called, then read all of http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/ for why `ajaxComplete` will not be called.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli I have and I am not familiar with Jquery all that well and its pretty much greek to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your not familiar with jQuery and cannot get a straight answer you can always use the jQuery migrate. This may help you if you cannot get any help here.

Comment: Thank you it worked I didn't want to add another file but it worked thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your `ajaxComplete` attached to the wrong place.
According to [documentation for .ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/)

> Additional Notes:
>
> As of jQuery 1.9, all the handlers for the jQuery global Ajax events, including those added with the .ajaxComplete() method, must be attached to document.
>
> If $.ajax() or $.ajaxSetup() is called with the global option set to false, the .ajaxComplete() method will not fire.

Try to change this part:  `$("#status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request) {`

**UPD:** Actually you don't even need this function in your implementation. `success` will do it for you

Comment: all it says when I run on new version of Jquery is Checking

Answer (score 1):

This answer might not be quite correct as it depends on the versions of jQuery you are referring to, however as of 3.0 the success, error and complete callbacks are removed. And should be replaced with done, fail & always.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

i.e.

```
$.ajax({
    type: method,
    url: url,
    data: ""
}).done(function (resp) {

}).fail(function (resp) {

}).always(function () {

});
```

Comment: You're wrong. They are deprecated as extension methods, but not as parameters. check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15821199/4121714 and please read carefully documentation that you provided. "The jqXHR object returned from jQuery.ajax() is a jQuery Deferred and has historically had three extra methods with names matching the arguments object of success, error, and complete. This often confused people who did not realize that the returned object should be treated like a Deferred. As of jQuery 3.0 these methods have been removed. As replacements, use the Deferred  ... " see comment above