# AJAX best practice in 2020 (success vs. done)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've been using jQuery (3.4.1) and code like the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'processing.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {ID: ID},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) { checkIfError(response);
        // do on success
    }, 
  error: handleError
});
```

And while it works fine, depending what you look at, it appears that this code is deprecated.

**Should I be using something like the following instead?**

```
$.post('processing.php', {ID: ID}, function(response){checkIfError(response);}, 'json')
.done(function (response) {
    // do on success
}).fail(handleError);
```

(My `checkIfError()` function checks if response is valid, otherwise triggers an appropriate message)

Or is there something better / preferred that I should be using now? (since many of the SO answers are quite dated, and something better might be available.)

**EDIT:**
Looking at this (also dated), it appears the success is only deprecated when used as a callback? So my prior code isn't actually deprecated?)
[Deprecation of success Parameter in jQuery.ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821141/deprecation-of-success-parameter-in-jquery-ajax)
(Still want to know best practice for 2020...)

Comment: They really are just two ways to do the exact same thing. The later just uses the Promise API which is really powerful as you can add multiple callbacks and pass the promise object itself around. Providing a callback in the options is not a bad practice in itself - a bad practice is the crap code jQuery ninjas write where they shove everything into a single insanely long callback function provided as the success option and every line ends up indented to the moon.

Comment: Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.
[https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)